# Why grails domain validation reject a url like http://wctest.jenkins:8080/CRMGateway

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Why grails domain validation  reject a url like http://wctest.jenkins:8080/CRMGateway. Though the url supplied is correct in structure.Do this want it be a url with no port?

Below is the domain that I have

```
class Configuration{
String username
String password
String gatewayURL

  //constraints
  static constraints = {
    gatewayUrl nullable: true, blank: false, url: true
  }
}
```

In bootstrap file, code is like

```
Configuration config = new configuration(username:'abc',password:new
SHA256("w3lc0m3"),"http://wctest.jenkins:8080/CRMGateway") 
config.save flush:true
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the default url validation rejects `wctest.jenkins`.

But it accepts `wctest.com` or `wctest.ch`.

If it is too restrictive, you will need to customize the validation (as in http://java.dzone.com/articles/grails-goodness-add-extra or using Grails custom validation).